# How to define methods dynamically for action mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer

I need to send various email like user_mail_#{type}*for*#{transaction_quantity}_#{transaction_status}.

here type, transaction_quantity and transaction_status can have multiple values.

I want to define all action_mailer methods dynamically because processing for those methods are almost same only templates are different and rails will automatically pickup templates according to method name .

Comment: What you need might be `define_method`

A nice explanation can be found here:

http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/02/ruby-dynamically-define-method.html

`define_method` allows you to create methods dynamically at runtime with a name that can depend on some variable - also you can use the method name within the method as parameter.

However: is it really necessary to have those in the method name?
Why can't you pass those values as parameters and pick the template within the mailer method?

Comment: I tried define_methods but don't know how to check if it is working or not. MailerClass.methods doesn't list those methods.

Yes, your other suggestion looks better. I think I will go with that.

thanks

Comment: Well, you can check it by writing test cases that follow the program up to that point and then call the methods - depending on how you actually called define_method: if inside a method call that method and then the generated method, if in the class "root" it will be there when using the class